# why Glassfish server throws NoSuchMethodError when creating an instance of java.time.LocalDate with ZoneId

Tags: java, localdate, glassfish-5

I have this code that creates an instance of java.time.LocalDate. I compiled it with JDK 14 and it runs without any error:

```
public void foo(Date d){
  LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.ofInstant(d.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
  System.out.println("Created LocalDate from Date: "+d1);
}
```

When I try to do the same thing inside a backing bean for a JSF page running on Glassfish server 5.1, it throws a NoSuchMethodError.

```
public void validateDateTimeLine(FacesContext fc, UIComponent ui, Object value) {
        Date then = (Date) value;
        try {
            LocalDate dthen = LocalDate.ofInstant(then.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
            ....................................
        } catch (Exception | NoSuchMethodError e) {
            
        }
}
```

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.time.LocalDate.ofInstant(Ljava/time/Instant;Ljava/time/ZoneId;)Ljava/time/LocalDate;
    at org.me.mavenlistservicedb.bean.LoginManagment.validateDateTimeLine(LoginManagment.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.validator.MethodExpressionValidator.validate(MethodExpressionValidator.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1037)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1334)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:2150)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:1273)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:269)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1332)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Java8 and further version regarding `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`, there were some changes from the one GlassFish uses (jre8) and the next ones, starting from Java9.

- **Java8**
  `ofInstant` is implemented on **`LocalDateTime`**
- **Java9+**

  `ofInstant` is implemented on **`LocalDate`**.

In order to follow your logic, you could do this:

```
LocalDateTime dTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(then.toInstant(),ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate dthen = dTime.toLocalDate();
```

**`LocalDateTime`**'s [`toLocalDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toLocalDate--) would allow you get the appropiate variable type : **`LocalDate`**

> **`public LocalDate toLocalDate()`**
>
> *Gets the LocalDate part of this
> date-time. This returns a LocalDate with the same year, month and day
> as this date-time.*

Comment: Good solution, but why did the code compile *and run* on Java 8 if the method doesn't exist for Java 8?

Comment: @Andreas I believe it's because its IDE's compiler is v14, but when trying to run it on another version (glassfish 5 uses java8), then a runtime exception happens (it was compiled ok, but at runtime sh** happens). I guess? : D

Comment: Thanks, aran, this might be the solution. I will try it tomorrow and will let you know the result.

Comment: Andeas: I have configured Netbeans with JDK 14. My Web application runs without any problem on Glassfish, which is using JDK 8, with the exception of this LocalDate. As I develop the code further, there might be more such inconsistencies. At some point, I am going to migrate the code to Jakarta, which I don't know much about right now but maybe they have an app server that runs on a more recent version of the JDK?

Comment: Hi @Darvin, from my point of view, this type of fixes should be just temporal;I suggest upgrading the servers in a ordered way (not all at the same time), while you start changing the --release metadata of the compiler to newer versions. One of the issues of being "behind" regarding java versions is possible incompabilities with another third party libraries, for example. Anyway, you do well asking Andreas, that's why knows better than me for sure.

Comment: @aran: absolutely.

Comment: @Darvin sincerely, that guy is a BOSS.

Comment: @aran - You are very good at finding a solution using the existing API. I've given such feedback earlier as well. Keep it up!

Comment: @LiveandLetLive I'm putting sentimental here... Thanks a lot for your words!! You are on of those users I respect at max, you are part of that top tier. You make me learn new things, this is sincere. Thank you for this Live and Let Live

Comment: @aran If the IDE's compiler is v14, then the code wouldn't run on Java 8. You have to tell the IDE to generate Java 8 compatible byte code using `-target 8` (or IDE equivalent). If you do that, you must also change the classpath to use a JDK 8 installation, or you get errors like seen in this question. That was obviously not done, so the cause of the error is that the **IDE is misconfigured**. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65753802/5221149) for how to fix. When correctly configured, the code would fail to compile, and need this answer to fix that.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for pointing this out. That's the common issue when trying to change the compile version while not setting the path for the desired versión jre/jdk, I'd upvote again your answer if I already didn't..

Comment: @Aran: Thank you, your recommendation works well and I no longer get an exception.

Comment: @Darvin you're so welcome, glad this was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

While the [LocalDate.ofInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofInstant(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)) method exists in Java 14, it does not in the [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class from Java 8. I'm expecting that you are compiling using JDK 14, but running it on a lower version of Java.

Comment: If the code was simply compiled with JDK 14, the generated bytecode wouldn't run with Java 8. It's a bit more complicated than that, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65753802/5221149).

Comment: Yes the entire Web application code was compiled with JDK 14, however, Glassfish 5.1 container is running on a variant of JDK8

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant, ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofInstant(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)), you will find:

> **Since:**
>
> 9

The code was compiled against a Java 9+ Runtime Library, but was compiled with `-target 1.8` and you're running with Java 8.

Don't do that, i.e. always make sure that you're compiling against the same version of the Runtime Library as the version of the generated bytecode.

*Solution:* Use compiler option **`--release 8`** instead of `-source 8 -target 8`. That option was specifically added to the Java 9+ compiler to make it easier to compile for older versions of Java against the correct version of the Runtime Library.

***Recommended:*** See [JEP 247: Compile for Older Platform Versions](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247) for more detail.

---

**UPDATE**

It is mentioned in comments to [aran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65753814/5221149) that NetBeans is used to compile the code. I don't have NetBeans, but I believe it functions very similar to the Eclipse I use, so I'll show how to fix this in Eclipse, and hope you can apply it yourself to NetBeans.

In Eclipse, you need to specify the target Java version in 2 places:

- The classpath (or buildpath in Eclipse):

  [image]
- The compiler compliance level (`-source` and `-target` on command-line):

  [image]

In the olden days, those two should always refer to the same version, e.g. as shown here, where the build path refers to where **JDK 15** is installed, and the compliance level is set to **15**.

Starting with Java 9 and the new `--release` compiler option, you can target older versions of Java, without the need to have such an older version installed.

Leaving the build path pointing to JDK 15, you can change the compliance version to e.g. 8, if you also check the `Use '--release' option` checkbox (circled in blue).

It is very important to check the `Use '--release' option` checkbox if you don't change the build path to match the compliance version.

Doing this will ensure that the compiler fails on the `LocalDate.ofInstant()` call, because that method didn't exist in JDK 8, even though you still have JDK 15  on the build path.

Comment: I thank you immensely for expounding the problem in such detail. Netbean set up is slightly different than Eclipse, in the sense that NB allows the user to pre-setup "platforms" (i.e. JDK 14, JDK 8, JDK 9, and so on). I have configured two such platforms JDK 14 (as the default platform) and JDK-8-update-144-for-Glassfish. There are no additional build options such "--release--" for Web Application development projects. This time, I selected the JDK-8-update-144-for-Glassfish to compile the source, and of course, it flagged LocalDate.ofInstant as an error and it cut the rope....

Comment: before I hung myself. Since I need this LocalDate.ofInstant functionality, I ended up using the approach suggested by Aran. Thanks again